# Using custom fonts with css font-face, different on different browsers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Let me give you some examples:

Firefox 13:

[image]

Chrome (latest):

[image]

As you can see, in Firefox the font appears smoother, and in Chrome choppier. I'm curious as to why this is happening and steps I can take to even out the experience for my users.

I'm using an .otf font:

```
HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn.otf
```

And using the following CSS rules to apply this custom font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue LTPro";
    src: url("/Public/assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-LtCn.otf");
}

a {
    color: #665548;                
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue LTPro";
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 17px;                
}
```

What do you recommend I use to even out the font differences? Or better yet, what's a good practice way to use "Web safe" fonts? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: see here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125297&q=aliasing%20custom%20fonts&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't just take any font, convert it and have it work well in all browsers. I'd love it if you could but you can't.

Your best bet for getting good results is to use a font delivery service such as [typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts) or [fontdeck](http://fontdeck.com/) that provide fonts that have been designed for delivery across browsers and so have a better chance of rendering consistently. You're still likely to get small variations across browsers and operating systems though, that's the nature of the web.

But in answer to your question specifically, there are no settings or workarounds to make that font appear consistently. For what it's worth I think they both look fine.

Comment: I'm new to font delivery services such as Typekit. If I use them, will they give my site actual selectable text, or a rendered image provider by their service? I need to know for SEO services.

Comment: Yes, they certainly will. The text will be rendered just as the text on this page, it will be selectable and search engine friendly and also look good. Have a look at Elliot Jay Stocks' site as a good example of what is possible: http://elliotjaystocks.com

Answer (score 0):

That's just depending on how a browser interprets the font. I've never actually used it, but there's a site called fontsquirrel that will take a font and break it up into different font extensions to be used for different browsers. Check it out. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/